# Java: How to print every output of the console either in the console and in a file?

Tags: java, file, console, output

Evening, I have this need:

Every output of the console should be printed into a file but also still in the console. and the /n should be changed with lineSeparator().

How can I achieve that?

Comment: With "every output of the console" you mean everything you send to `System.out`?

Comment: Try System.getProperty("line.separator")

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto that's right

Comment: Id write a new class with a static method handling messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a `PrintStream` to `System.out` with [`System.setOut()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-).

Thus you have to implement a `PrintStream` that outputs its input to the old `System.out` and a file simultaneously. (Overriding the [`FilterOutputStream.write()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#write-byte:A-) method.)

Answer (score 1):

You can print the output in output file by using FileOutputStream and PrintStream, You can try below code for better understanding.

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        java.io.File outFile = new java.io.File ("File name" );
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
        System.setOut(ps);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

This code prints the output in the text file, If the text file does not exist then it creates a new file and then prints output in the file.